# NetSuite Reporting At BOM Component Level

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suiteql

Has anyone used SuiteQL or any other approach to get sales/usage history per item but at the BOM component level? This would be for Advanced BOM setup as well. Ex. would be a Sales Order line with an Assembly item that has an Assembly item that has a BOM Revision with 5 different components with different BOM qtys. How can you capture the qtys sold for the components on that Sales Order line? Thanks in advance!!

I have been trying to link with SuiteQL but having a difficult time getting the joins correct.

Comment: Are you trying to determine how many (if any) of each of the components in the BoM have been sold separately  ?
I think the question needs more detail to help provide an answer.